# Validation Message Issue + Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

When I click the radio button, the above field's validation is automatically applied, Without clicking on the submit button. Is there a way to remove that functionality?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Disable Contact Form 7 Field Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925237/dynamically-disable-contact-form-7-field-validation)

Comment: See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925237/dynamically-disable-contact-form-7-field-validation).